# Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a REST service that I want to use my angular app. I added 2 changes to my code that cause an exception.

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module xxx due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module xxx.pages due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Profile due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Profile' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

services/service.js

```
angular.module('xxx.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('Profile', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/v1/profile', {}, {
      query: { method:'GET' }
    });
  }]);
```

pages/pages.js

```
angular.module('xxx.pages', ['xxx.grandfather', 'Profile'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      templateUrl: 'cmp/pages/admin.tpl.html',
      accessLevel: accessLevels.admin
    })
    .state('app.user', {
      url: '/user',
      templateUrl: 'cmp/pages/user.tpl.html',
      controller: 'UserController',
      accessLevel: accessLevels.user
    });
})
.controller('UserController', function ($scope, Profile) {
  $scope.profile = Profile.query();
});
```

I tired all the google resulsts:

- ng-app is there and it was working fine before
- xxx.services.Profile and all combinations
- included angular-route.js

Comment: In `angular.module('xxx.pages', [..., 'Profile'])` you define a module named `xxx.pages` that depends on a *module* called `Profile`. But in `angular.module('xxx.services',...).factory('Profile',...)` you define a *service* called `Profile`.

Comment: As @NikosParaskevopoulos said, you need to depend on `'xxx.services'`

Comment: Oh, I see. So in other words `['xxx.services']` is roughly and equivalent of java `import xxx.services.*;`